# WSO2 ESB - WSAddressing Set To Header

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to get WSO2 to work with WCF - WCF expects the WSAddressing headers to be set and correct. I am trying to use a Header Mediator with my WSDL Proxy Service and to set the To Header but it never seems to do anything - I always get the error message from WCF: "The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree."

Here is my proxy setup - what do I need to do to get this working?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="PingService"
       transports="http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <header xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
                 name="a:To"
                 scope="default"
                 value="http://localhost/PingService/PingService.svc"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <wsdl service="PingService"
               port="AccountService_WsHttp"
               uri="http://uk-dev-10706.wintech.local/PingService/PingService.svc?singleWsdl"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can enable "WS-Addressing" for your endpoint.

http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/WSDL+Endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Please try with transport scope may be that will work in your case.

```
 <header xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
                 name="a:To"
                 scope="transport"
                 value="http://localhost/PingService/PingService.svc"/>
```